# kendo datepicker - set date without looking maxdate

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker

I have one kind of scenario using date picker. I have date picker with max date=current date + 10 days,on page load only i want to show date more than the max date,but I'm  allowing user to enter only up to max date. Is it possible. Without looking maxing date i want to display only the date what ever i want.code:-

```
var datepicker = $("#date" + uid).data("kendoDatePicker");
                    var addDays = new Date();
                    if (arr[1] == "") {
                        var d = new Date();
                        datepicker.min(new Date());
                        datepicker.max(new Date(d.getDate() , d.getMonth(), d.getDate()+ parseInt(arr[1]) - parseInt(1)));
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is achievable. But what if you try to add two date pickers instead? One that display only the text, and the other only the calendar button. You need to play a bit the CSS, but I think it could spare you a lot of time.